# Admob request are 12000 but impressions are 6000 match rate is 98 i dontknow why impressions are less

Tags: android, admob, google-play-services, ads

I am using Admob  ads
but i don't know it is an issue are not is it normal need your guidelines
last 7 days I get 12000 requests but impressions are just 6000
and the match rate is 99% don't know where my 6000 request goes is it normal?
I think it is an issue or sometimes users are in that location where AdMob have zero ads thats way is it true?

Comment: do you have a GDPR modal to handle and pass the user consent to Admob ?

Comment: No i have not why ?

Comment: If some of your users are in Europe, you might be interested in looking into this : https://developers.google.com/admob/ump/android/quick-start

Comment: i didn't understand what you post and what is my question :(